# Is 1h25m enough to connect at Frankfurt am Main Airport?

Tags: layovers, short-connections

I have a flight from India to Frankfurt and Frankfurt to London via Lufthansa. I have a layover of 1 hour and 25 mins. Is this enough to connect?
I am travelling with an Indian Passport.

Comment: It is probably plenty of time, if both flights are LH and the luggage is checked in to London.

Comment: By the way, note that Indian nationals transiting in Germany normally need an airport transit visa, though there are exceptions.

Comment: @fkraiem: If he has a visa for the UK, though, then he's exempt from needing an airport transit visa.

Comment: Single ticket: yes. Two separate tickets: no

Answer (score 2):

If the airline is willing to sell you the ticket *they* believe you can connect -- because they're on the hook for rebooking you if you don't make it.

Further, there are plenty of flights to be rebooked on -- on the random October date I just searched for, Lufthansa alone has *fifteen* non-stop flights from Frankfurt to either Heathrow or London City, spread out over the day. So no matter how late your incoming flight is, you can expect to be on a flight to London with at most a few hours wait in Frankfurt (unless you miss the last flight of the day, in which case you'll have to wait for an early-morning flight the next day). It's not like some other connections where missing your flight could mean you have to wait for the same flight the next day.

Comment: Hey! Thank you. Yes I do have a VISA for the U.K. 
@Henning - what you said, makes sense. Thanks

Comment: one issue though, Henning ..... "because they're on the hook for rebooking you if you don't make it."  ... we live in a fascinating era where airlines **simply ignore** this concept.  (Especially in the US.)  With the US air transport system falling apart, it's becoming basically the norm that flight connections are missed.  The airlines simply do - nothing.  (1) they have endless fine print to get out of it ("weather!" etc).   (2) They have the policy "What are you going to do - litigate?"

Comment: The last year or two in the US, every single time an airline has f'd me over, they have done utterly nothing to make-up.

Comment: Hi @Yasha in your specific case with Frankfurt: I have done that very trip a number of times and yes it's no problem.  It's a great airport.  That being said, if your incoming flight is an hour late it will be tight.  (But then, if you have a 5 hour break, and the flight is 5 hrs late, it will be tight!)

Comment: @Fattie In EU airlines are liable for looking after you in this scenario. You would be accommodated somewhere and receive a meal voucher. If the airline was at fault compensation would apply.